# How to take database backup on heroku without pgbackups addon?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm looking for a way to take database backup on heroku without using pgbackups addon. Is there any gem which can help in this situation? The gem should not also use command line command `pg_dump`.

Comment: Where do you want to keep the backup?

Comment: I want to keep backups on S3.

Answer (score 2):

You can save a copy to your development environment by using this command:

```
heroku db:pull
```

Answer (score 0):

I set my env to (`PGHOST`, `PGPORT`, `PGDATABSE`, `PGUSER`, `PGPASSWORD`) to the Heroku instance and then run:

`pg_dump --clean --blobs | sed 's/db_user_on_heroku/db_user_on_local/g' > /tmp/db.pg`

I then set the env to point to my local DB, and run:

`psql < /tmp/db.pg`

Comment: the OP didn't want to make use of pg_dump for whatever reason.